# Cannot re-use product identifier, how to fix?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I stupidly deleted two product identifiers from the apple application loader and i'm aware that I can't re-use these id's but this presents a problem as the id is generated app side when the user selects a specific cell in the purchase screen and this number was appended to the purchase id i.e.
B117E4 = cell 4 in the collection viewController
Now i've deleted B117E4 and B117E5 from my list this effectively rules out IAP 4 & 5 from my collection viewController. Does anyone have any thoughts regarding a workaround please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't use the same identifier as previously stated so I had to suffix a letter in my code just for those IAP's. Painful but couldn't find any other way round it.